# API to toggle "Show hidden files, folders and drives"

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-explorer, windows-shell

Is there a function in Windows API to toggle the "Show hidden files, folders and drives" option in Windows Explorer (Tools >> Folder Options... >> View tab).

I know of a related registry key, but changing that would not have immediate effect. The key is: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/Advanced/Hidden`

Trying to do this from C#, but the question is not language-specific.

Comment: Not knowing why you're trying to do this, can I just ask - are you sure this is the right solution to whatever problem you have? http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx

Comment: I'm making a utility to show/hide hidden attributes for groups of files. Therefore, I want to pop up a warning if hidden files are visible in Explorer, and have the user click to fix it.

Comment: @Damien Thanks for the link,I read Raymond's blog as well :) It's common sense not to use global OS state to fix a local problem, so a warning is appropriate.

Comment: Ah, that seems reasonable. I'll leave comment/answer as a warning for others

Answer (score 4):

You could try the options the OP in [this thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31604553/getting-explorer-to-rerea.aspx) suggests, that is:

Either

```
 SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);
```

or

```
 RefreshPolicyEx(False, RP_FORCE);
```

or

```
 SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, integer(pchar('Policy')), SMTO_NORMAL or SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, c1);
```

These are not in the .NET C# API, so you'll have to use `DllImport`

Edit: formatting

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comment I've added to the original question - if you're doing this so that, for instance, the OpenFileDialog you're about to pop open shows these files - don't do it.

In that case, you're better P/Invoking [GetOpenFileName](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comdlg32/GetOpenFileName.html), and setting the appropriate option (OFN_FORCESHOWHIDDEN (see [enum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/2f4dd95e-5c7b-4f48-adfc-44956b350f38) for a related subject) in the flags of the [OpenFileName](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/OpenFileName.html) structure.

That way you're only affecting *your* application, at the appropriate time

Answer (score 1):

I know of no API, but the registry key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Hidden`.  From experimentation, it seems a value of 1 means show and a value of 2 means hide.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but if you took the time to check you'd see that OP's question was amended to include the registry key a few days after my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[SHGetSetSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762200(VS.85).aspx)

[SHELLSTATE Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759788(v=VS.85).aspx)
fShowAllObjects
BOOL
TRUE to show all objects, including hidden files and folders. FALSE to hide hidden files and folders.

fShowSysFiles
BOOL
TRUE to show system files, FALSE to hide them.

Spy++ says a WM_SETTINGCHANGE is sent to the explorer windows.

Comment: It works to change the setting. Unfortunately, in Windows 7 explorer does not get updated (WM_SETTINGCHANGE does not help).